# free() replaces string with zero?

Tags: c, string, free

I could use a little help with free().

When I run the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char *mystring = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(mystring, "Hello");
    printf("%p\n", mystring);
    printf("%s\n", mystring);
    free(mystring);
    printf("%p\n", mystring);
    printf("%d\n", *mystring);

    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
0x8f46008
Hello
0x8f46008
0
```

Did free() replace the string 'Hello' from memory with zero?

Note: This is just for academic purposes. I would never reference freed memory for real.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: In addition to the excellent answers, please don't ever multiply by `sizeof(char)` - it's always guaranteed to be 1 and it clogs up the code.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have `free`d a block of memory, reading that memory again results in undefined behavior and is a serious security and stability hazard.  You cannot count on anything holding true for memory that has been `free`d, so there is no guarantee whether the memory will be zeroed or not.  Unless you are absolutely sure of what you're doing, *don't reference memory after you've freed it.*

As an amusing anecdote about this, the original SimCity game had a bug in it where it referenced memory that had been freed.  In DOS, this ended up not causing a crash, but when it was ported to Windows the game started crashing repeatedly.  The Windows team had to specifically build in a case into the OS such that if SimCity was run, a custom memory manager would be used to prevent this sort of crash.  You can read the full story [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000054.html).

In short, once it's freed, don't touch it.  Otherwise you risk bugs that some poor programmer years down the line will have to fix for you.  Tools like valgrind exist to detect these sorts of errors specifically because they're so nasty.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. I've always thought that ISO should have defined "undefined behaviour" as requiring the compiler to make a hand come out of the monitor and slap the developer around the head until they fixed it. Originally, my proposal was for electrical connections between the computer and developer testicles (or equivalent for ladies) but I've mellowed in my old age :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo- While in general I agree, some things like bitshifts on signed values or integer overflow also result in undefined behavior.  Developers wouldn't last a week if they got slapped every time they did something like this. :-)

Comment: SimCity thing is also at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/APIWar.html - though this is the reason why Windows is five times the size it _could_ be, I understand the need to keep old customers working when upgrading.

Comment: @paxdiablo: While your comment is obviously intended as an exaggeration, there is a lot of undefined behavior that can absolutely be detected at compile time and which the standard *could* mandate that compilers either "should" or "must" reject at compile time or emit code that aborts the program. For instance reaching a statement like `x = x++;` should abort the program; there's no excuse for compilers assigning behavior to statements like this, and it just encourages buggy code.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `mystring` (`*mystring`, `mystring[0]`, and friends) are *undefined* after you `free` the memory. You can not rely on it containing "Hello". You also cannot rely on it containing an ASCII NUL (as you see here).

You also cannot rely on reading it not causing a *segmentation fault*. **Don't do it**.

If you were to run this program in a memory checker like `valgrind`, you would see an error here about access to freed memory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in debug mode on your specific computer and compiled with your specific compiler, in general though you should expect that piece of code to crash (or worse).